# Responsive design with GetSkeleton: how to float right or left by media-type?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using Skeleton to make an existing site responsive, and there's one thing I can't figure out.

```
<div class="sixteen columns">
<div class="ten columns alpha">HEADER</div>
<div class="six columns omega" style="float:right;">search box</div>
</div>
```

This looks good if the two columns are next to each other, like this:

```
| HEADER                      search box |
```

But if the screen is smaller and the columns are vertically stacked, it stacks okay but the float looks less good:

```
| HEADER              |
|          search box |
```

How can I float the search box left when the columns stack?

Do I need to amend the search-box's float style using Skeleton's media-types?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to amend the search-box's float style using [[media queries](http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/)]?

Yes. :-)

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
      .search-box{
           float:left;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple media query to achieve this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  .omega{
     float:left;
  }
}
```

`max-width` means, when the viewport is *less-than* then apply the updated style. You can also use `min-width` which works much in the same way however it means *greater-than* and will apply the style once the viewport is bigger than the width.